# Setting a paragraphs CSS width through Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Javascript, I have a div with a paragraph inside it. I have made an effect where the div slowly expands in width & reveals the text in the paragraph below.

I set the divs width to zero, then every 10 milliseconds I increase the width by 10px.  This works great because I have set the div to have overflow hidden.

**My Problem:** BUT the text in the paragraph wraps to the current width of the parent div, which means that the text jumps around & reformats as the width increases.

I want to remove/stop this from occuring so I explicity set the paragraphs width to 100px (the width of the div once it has completely expanded) but the problem is when I go check the CSS width of the paragraph element in Firebug, its not set, ie its not listed in the HTML elements inline CSS style?

It makes me think that a paragraph element by default has display block & ignores the width parameter, is that correct?

**My ultimate question is:** How can I get the paragraph element to be 100px wide? Do I need to change the display type to get the width to work?

This doesn't work:

pEle.style.width = "100px"; 
   // maybe I need to change the display type before I set its width?

Comment: Can you provide your code, markup and style? Preferably in a http://jsfiddle.com?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can do this just be explicitly setting a width for the paragraph in your CSS.

By default a paragraph element is block level and will take take any width you specify... Leads me to think somethings going wrong with how you're trying set the width.

Here's a quick fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MerlinMason/Sdq65/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I truly believe all your problems maybe fixed by adding this css property to your paragraph:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```